# Please welcome your new moderator!

Tags: discussion, moderation

I'm Pops, a Community Manager at Stack Exchange. Today, I'm sad to announce that one of your longtime moderators has left the team, but happy to announce a great replacement:

[image: mrRoad]

It's been a while since the last change in mods, so for those who need a refresher: we select a few members from each community to act as provisional moderators, for sites between "brand new" and "graduated" status. (Although your logo still says "beta," we've [moved on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) from thinking of you as being in a trial period; our wording just hasn't caught up yet.) You can read about the program on our blog: [Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

Please join me in thanking Denny Conn for his service and welcoming Mr_road!

Comment: Thank you Pops! Hello everyone, I hope I can help you all get as much information and enjoyment out of this site as I have :) And, Thank you again.

Comment: @Mr_road Congratulations.

Comment: Welcome Mr Road. May your way be long and winding.... And - thank you Denny Conn!